# Linq-To-Sql LoadWith commands

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How can I get ahold of the `SqlCommand`s for the queries used to fetch child-records when running with `LoadWith` options?

Suppose a schema like this (very shorthand, but should explain what's going on):

```
Widget:
   Id int not null identity(1,1) primary key
   IsNeeded bit not null

DooHickey
   Id int not null identity(1,1) primary key
   WidgetFk int not null references Widget(Id)
```

Translated to Linq-To-Sql classes using the drag and drop interface in visual studio.

Example:

```
using(var ctx = GetDataContext()) {
  var dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
  dlo.LoadWith(widget => widget.DooHickeys);
  ctx.LoadOptions = dlo;
  var query = ctx.Widgets.Where(x => x.IsNeeded);

  // The "select * from Widget where IsNeeded = 1" command
  var mainCmd = (SqlCommand)ctx.GetComamnd(query);

  // Want Command for getting the DoHickeys
}
```

This'll make it easier to automate creating SqlDependencies for a `DataContext` and `IQueryable`.  Perhaps I'm doing it the hard way and someone has already solved this...I'd accept a third party tool (NuGet installable please) that didn't introduce new dependencies (like System.Web) as well.

Comment: I don't see how you'd arrive at an EXISTS from a LoadWith. LoadWith produces a JOIN. If you do `query.ToString()` you'll see it.

Comment: AH, maybe I should have been clearer that I don't know how the LoadWith works under the hood, although I overall understand how Linq-To-Sql queries function.  When I `GetCommand` it doesn't show a join...

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = ctx.Widgets.Where(x => x.IsNeeded);
```

should be

```
var query = ctx.Widgets.Where(x => x.IsNeeded == 1);
```

Comment: Also, `bit` in SqlServer gets translated as a boolean.

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl - I've no idea what type IsNeeded is since you did not show that in your quest.  Make the change with a correct type and see the result you want.  Or don't.  No matter to me.